# Can I run any docker container in Microsoft Iot Edge?

Tags: docker, azure-iot-edge

IoT Edge from Microsoft uses docker for managing modules.
Is it possible to run any docker container on a IoT Edge device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run any kind of docker-based container on IoT Edge as long as the image supports the architecture your Edge device uses (amd64, arm32, etc.) The container does not have to be aware of IoT Edge or even talk to the runtime. In this case the Edge runtime will simply make sure the container is up and running according to your settings.